# Problem after installing Compiz on Arch+XFCE4

Tags: arch-linux, compiz

I have installed `compiz-bzr` and `emerald-git` by following commands :

```
yaourt -S compiz-bzr
yaourt -S emerald-git
```

And then I have tried :

```
emerald --replace
```

And now all windows are without borders. docky's animation does not work any more. and many other problems...

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Any helps would be awesome.

Comment: Why are you using development versions of those packages? Does the same happen using the stable packages?

Comment: @Wieland `compiz-bzr` is stand alone version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable `Window Decoration` in `ccsm`? Otherwise no border is available.

Also you should start `compiz` instead, which would call `emerald`

Comment: I tried `compiz --replace` and windows borders comes back fine. After that tried `ccsm` in terminal but does not run anything... !